# How to Sum Value's of a column in a Table using Lookup function

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have two Datasets i.e Dataset1 and Dataset 2 both have columns like
(System has Similar Values in Both Dataset)

Dataset1-System , work , food

Dataset2-System , total , complete

Value in Column (DATASET2) "Total" is like 1,18,4 and in "Complete" its like 1,0,4.

I want to use Dataset2 in the same Tablix as Dataset1
and I would like to get the result by summing up total and complete

`=Lookup(Fields!SYSTEM.Value ,Fields!SYSTEM.Value, Fields!COMPLETE.Value , "DATASET2"))/Lookup(Fields!SYSTEM.Value ,Fields!SYSTEM.Value, Fields!TOTAL.Value,"DATASET2"))`

Tried this as well as included SUM in both like

```
=SUM(Lookup(Fields!SYSTEM.Value ,Fields!SYSTEM.Value, Fields!COMPLETE.Value , "MANI"))/SUM(Lookup(Fields!SYSTEM.Value ,Fields!SYSTEM.Value, Fields!TOTAL.Value,"DATASET2"))
```

Tried more combinations Nothing Worked

Required result:-  `" SUM(TOTAL)/SUM(COMPLETE) "` using LOOKUP
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Hi Mani, instead of stories, please provide (1) Queries to CREATE your tables including indexes. (2) Queries  to INSERT sample data. (3) The desired result given the sample, as text or image of excel for example. (4) A short description of the business rules, and how you got 1-2 of the results. (5) Which version of SQL Server you are using (this will help to fit the query to your version).

Comment: Hey Ronen just to simplify how can i create an Expression in Report Builder 2016 , To add and divide two columns using LOOKUP function

Comment: [This link can help in learning how to add expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expressions-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017), and once you know how to work with expressions, than [this link will help you regarding using Math expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017#math-functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but just looks like you're using the wrong function.  Also, you may be using too many parenthesis in the top expression.  You want to use the `SUM` on a `LookupSet` function.  This will return all the values of `COMPLETE` and `TOTAL` in a list that you can add together.  Try the following expression.

```
=(SUM(LookupSet(Fields!SYSTEM.Value ,Fields!SYSTEM.Value, Fields!COMPLETE.Value , "DATASET2")))
 /(SUM(LookupSet(Fields!SYSTEM.Value ,Fields!SYSTEM.Value, Fields!TOTAL.Value,"DATASET2")))
```